# Rotaion Surfaces and Complex Numbers

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, surfaces, surface-integrals

Consider a continuous invertible map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and define the follwing surface
$$
s:\mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}
$$
$$
\qquad xe^{i\theta} \longmapsto (x, \varphi(x)e^{i\theta})
$$
Can we say that $s$ defines a manifold which is isomorphic to the rotation surface generated by $\varphi$? In addition, consider a disc
$$
\mu : [0, r)\times[0, 2\pi)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}
$$
$$
\qquad \qquad \quad \ (x, \theta) \longmapsto xe^{i\theta}
$$
I would like to compute the integral
$$
\int_{[0, r)\times [0, 2\pi)}s\circ \mu
$$
In other words, I would like to find a formula to compute the "area" of a disc that "streches out" on the surface defined by $s$. I need such a formulation for practical purposes. Please forgive me if the notation is ambiguous, or if the question is obvious to theoreticians.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually one of the standard formulas in a first-year calculus course for the surface area of a surface of revolution. You want to compute the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r \phi(u)\sqrt{1+\phi'(u)^2}\,du\,d\theta.$$
(This is the surface obtained by rotating the graph $y=\phi(x)$ about the $x$-axis.)

Alternatively, you can derive this using the formula for a surface integral with a parametrization $\mathbf g(r,\theta)$,
$$\iint \left\|\frac{\partial\mathbf g}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf g}{\partial\theta}\right\|\,dr\,d\theta,$$
which you'll find in the latter parts of any calculus book.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a reference of a book where I can find such formulas?

Comment: You can find this in any standard calculus book. Or see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution#Area_formula) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral), for starters, on wikipedia.